# how can i render multiple actions in one call?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

how can i render multiple different actions in one call to a speccific controller?
**Html.RenderAction()** / **Html.Action()** only handles one controller&action. 
But what if i want in one call to render different views on the screen?

thanks in advance,
Sagiv

EDIT:
Hi again.
I'm not sure you understood my question.
**this is the cshtml:**

```
   <div id="menu">@using (Ajax.ActionLink("click me", "SomeAction","SomeController", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "showMsg", OnFailure = "showError" }))</div>
    <div id="div1">bla bla content</div>
....
    <div id="div2">bla bla content</div>
```

**and this is the controller:**

```
 public class SomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult SomeAction()
        {         
            return View("somethingfordiv1", ModelForDiv1);
            return View("somethingfordiv2", ModelForDiv2); //i want also return another view here
        }
     }
```

in this ajax call on the controller, i want to return 2 different views for 2 different divs.
thanks again :)

Comment: why not return one model for both divs?

Comment: because they are at different sections on the page. i don't want to refresh the whole page (this is why it's an ajax call). also- each section has it's own logic for display. i just want that in one call i'll render 2 different sections on the same page.

Comment: why can't you make two actions and than two ajax call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could proceed. You could aggregate the two view models into a unique view model and then have the controller action return a view containing javascript which will inject the two view results into the different divs.

As always start with the view models:

```
public class Model1 { }
public class Model2 { }

public class AggregatedModel
{
    public Model1 Model1 { get; set; }
    public Model2 Model2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        var model = new AggregatedModel
        {
            Model1 = new Model1(),
            Model2 = new Model2()
        };
        Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
        return PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

Then the corresponding `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` view:

```
<div id="menu">
    @Html.ActionLink("click me", "SomeAction", "Home", new { id = "clickme" })
</div>

<div id="div1">bla bla content</div>
<div id="div2">bla bla content</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#clickme').click(function () {
        $.getScript(this.href);
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Next the `~/Views/Home/SomeAction.cshtml` view:

```
@model AggregatedModel
$('#div1').html(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Html.Partial("Model1", Model.Model1).ToHtmlString())));
$('#div2').html(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Html.Partial("Model2", Model.Model2).ToHtmlString())));
```

and finally the two `~/Views/Home/Model1.cshtml` and `~/Views/Home/Model2.cshtml` views:

```
@model Model1
<span>This is the contents for model1</span>
```

and:

```
@model Model2
<span>This is the contents for model2</span>
```

Comment: that's a good idea. too bad Microsoft doesn't have a build in rendering options for multiple views. Html.Action() can render only one view. Same as Ajax.ActionLink().

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render different views on the screen return a model which represents the data for those views, then you can use RenderPartial and pass the part of the model data required to each view.

You can also use viewdata to separately have this available.

Html.RenderAction is also available but simulates another full request

---

For your ajax request you can return a html chunk from the rendering of a partial view and this can be determined by Request.IsAjaxRequest.  Then your javascript can set the result into the document.

This is in your action

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    return View("PartialViewName", partialModel);
}
return View("NormalView", normalModel);
```

And the client side example (using jquery)

```
    function hijack(form) {
        $("div#SearchResults").html("");
        $("div#SearchResults").addClass('loading');

        $.ajax({
            url: form.action,
            type: form.method,
            dataType: "html",
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $("div#SearchResults").removeClass('loading');
                $("div#SearchResults").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: hi, and thanks for the quick answer. i'm using an ajax calll (let say from a left menu) so when i click on the menu i want to render 2 different views (containers) with new controls depends on what was clicked. i'm using Ajax.ActionLink for that. so how can i render 2 different views (come from 2 different controllers) for that?